# EditText not saving user input in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

Iam new to android. My code includes creating two fragments.Fragment1 contains EditText and button. Upon clicking button the user input in EditText need to be updated in TextView in Fragment2. My problem is that the EditText is not storing the user input and Fragment2 is not inflated when i write onActivityCreated() method.Thanks in Advance for the solutions.
**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment1,fragmentOne);
            ft.add(R.id.fragment2,fragmentTwo);
            ft.commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MainActivity",e.toString()) ;
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    View v = null ;
    EditText name;
    Button b;
    String value = "";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
            name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
            b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
            return v;
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                value = name.getText().toString();
                clickMe(value);
            }
        });
    }
    public void clickMe(String value){
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("Name",value);
        this.setArguments(b);
    }
}
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
    public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String name = "";
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            name = bundle.getString("Name");
            }
        TextView display = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.display);
        display.setText(name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell what exactly are you trying to do here? What I mean is - are you building your own app or are you trying to fix already existing application?

Comment: Building my own app. Just practising Fragments concept.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're building your own app and seeing how you approached all this, let me give you few suggestions:

1. In-App navigation can be greatly simplified with use of Android Jetpack Navigation Component. Check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation
2. I also advise you to get acquainted with basic application architecture. I suggest taking a look at MVVM as per official android documentation. Read more here:
   https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide
3. If you manage to get this far, you should probably also learn:

- ViewModels: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel
- LiveData: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

This can seem as too much, but if you're looking to do things the right way, I suggest going by this route.